# Hamburger dropdown menu does not open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem, been dealing with it for a day now. My dropdown hamburger menu wont open up when resizing the browser window into a smaller size. The icon is showing, but when clicked nothing happens. I have no CSS for this one, yet. The CSS-file i have linked is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv-se">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <title>Satsafett</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap -->

  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="satsafettBS.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

 <!-- Header -->

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="mainNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">satsafett</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Speltips</a></li>
        <li><a href="oddsbonusar.html">Oddsbonusar</a></li>
        <li><a href="tv-matcher.html">TV-matcher</a></li>
        <li><a href="casinobonusar.html">Casinobonusar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

you have wrong value in data-target attribue. It should be:

```
data-target="#mainNavBar"
```

You are missing hash

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">satsafett</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu Items -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Speltips</a></li>
        <li><a href="oddsbonusar.html">Oddsbonusar</a></li>
        <li><a href="tv-matcher.html">TV-matcher</a></li>
        <li><a href="casinobonusar.html">Casinobonusar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  
   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DavidPeltomaa Accept the answer if it has helped you. That's how SO works and accepting an answer prevents spam answers as well.